# Subquery returning multiple columns

Tags: mysql, subquery, having

I am writing a select subquery that returns a COUNT. However, I need to use a HAVING clause in the subquery and as a result need to specify that column in my subquery SELECT.  So the result is that I have 2 columns:  COUNT and column_for_having_clause.

Is there any way that i can tell SQL to take just the first column.  I get an error saying 
"Operand should contain 1 column(s)". I figure this must be a common problem, does anyone know a way around it?

Also, is there a way you can execute a HAVING clause without specifying the column in your SELECT query?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be easier to answer with a specific set of data and what you want to return.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
SELECT blah FROM foo WHERE bar = (SELECT cnt FROM (SELECT cnt, column_for_having_clause FROM table .... HAVING ... LIMIT 1))
```

Quite ugly however.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can specify virtually any expression you want in the `HAVING` clause.  It doesn't have to be a column from the select-list.

```
SELECT ...
FROM foo
WHERE x = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bar 
           GROUP BY y HAVING y = MAX(y));
```

But you can also, if you're comparing the count to something in the outer query, compare tuples.

```
SELECT ...
FROM foo
WHERE (x, 1) = (SELECT COUNT(*), y = MAX(y) AS is_max FROM bar
                GROUP BY y HAVING is_max = 1);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply...but I get "unknown column" errors whenever I add a column in the having clause that I didn't have in the select 

Why would that be?

Comment: It would help if you edit your question and show the SQL query.